# Fast way to generate a vector of successive powers in DolphinDB

Tags: python, vectorization, pow, dolphindb, auto-vectorization

Suppose the base value is x, I would like to create a vector [1, x, x** 2, x** 3,.... , x**n-1] where the i-th element is Xi.

I know in Python it can be implemented with a list. For x=5 and n=10:

```
[pow(x,i) for i in range(10)]
```

[1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, 15625, 78125, 390625, 1953125]

Is there a way to do this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the built-in function `pow(x,y)` in DolphinDB. When the parameter x is a given base value and y is a vector, it returns the desired result.

```
x=5
n=10
pow(x,0..(n-1))
```

output:

```
[1,5,25,125,625,3125,15625,78125,390625,1953125]
```